Is it possible to set unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure in a `data:text/html` WebView
I generate a WebView as follows:
        val encodedHtml = generateEncodedHtml()
        webView.loadData(encodedHtml, "text/html", "base64")
    }

    private fun generateEncodedHtml(): String {
        val html = """
            <html>
                <head>
                    <title>My Form</title>
                    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
                    <script type="module" src="https://example.com/script.js" async defer></script>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <form action="" method="POST">

                    </form>
                </body>
            </html>
        """.trimIndent()
        return Base64.encodeToString(html.toByteArray(), Base64.NO_PADDING)

My script (example.com/script.js) needs access to window.crypto.subtle but this seems to only be available in a secure HTTPS context.
Is it possible to enable the flag chrome://flags/#unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure for this WebView and get the window.crypto library to work?
